# how to fix this query when i use limit in it?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am attempting to retrieve a single record from a table using the SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM your_table LIMIT 1;
```

However, I am encountering an issue and need assistance in understanding why this query is not returning the expected result. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Additionally, I have checked the table structure and confirmed that the data exists in the table. I have also reviewed the query syntax for any errors, but I have not been able to identify the issue. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has any recommendations for troubleshooting this issue, I would be grateful for your input. Thank you for your assistance.

I have also considered checking for any constraints or filters that may be affecting the query results, but I have not found any that would explain the issue. Any guidance on potential areas to investigate would be valuable.

Comment: You'll need to update your question with the concrete results you are getting and the ones you are expecting. Nobody can help you based on "not returning the expected result".

Comment: That query can't work in Oracle (tags you used) as it doesn't support LIMIT clause. So, yes - as user272... said said, we need some sample data to work with, along with database you really use.

Comment: There is no LIMIT keyword, so you have a syntax error. From Oracle 12.1 there is the `fetch first` clause: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, LIMIT is not supported. You can use this code when running sql query in mysql, but it will not work in Oracle. It cannot be used in Mssql either. 'Top(1)' is the equivalent of this.

If you use this code in Oracle, you will encounter the following error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

In Oracle, its equivalent is rownum.
Rownum corresponds to the row number of the records in the table, and if you use it as follows, it will work without any problems;

```
SELECT * FROM Your_Table WHERE ROWNUM=1
```